# Laravel 4 validation message attributes

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm running into an issue with custom validation messages. Here's my code:

```
$input = array( 
  'email' => Input::get('email'));
                        
$messages = array(
  'email.required' => 'The darn email is required man!',
  'email.exists'    => 'That email address is already being used!',
  'email.email' => 'Bad email, Bad.');
                      
$rules = array(
  'email' => 'required|exists:users,email|email');
```

My passback to the Laravel view is:

```
@foreach( $errors->all() as $message )
    <li>{{ $message }}</li>
@endforeach
```

With this, I enter no email address and get:

> "The darn email is required"

... Good!

Then I enter an email address that exists in the DB:

> "That email address is already being used!"

... Good!

Then I enter an invalid email address like "noemail":

> "That email address is already being used!"
>
> "Bad email, Bad."

Why am I getting two messages when I should only be getting the one associated with the email.email custom attribute? (i.e., the "Bad email, Bad." message)?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out....

needed to be using the `unique:table,column` option, not `exists`.